# Solver foundation simplex solution takes a lot of time

Tags: c#, ms-solver-foundation

Trying to solve the following problem using Solver foundation:

**Given:** range: {x | x from double} and points: {(x,y) | x,y from double}

Find piece wise linear function - { (a,b) | a,b from double} where:

- Linear lines drawn are between the x'es from range.
- Covers all the points.
- Minimal area under the graph.

**Example:** range: {1, 2, 3} , points {(1,40), (1.5,40), (2.5,70)}

[image]

**My solution:**

Minimize the following problem with Simplex:

foreach i range add :

```
var ai = new Decision(Domain.RealRange(0, 100), null);
var bi = new Decision(Domain.RealRange(0, 100), null);
model.AddDecisions(a, b);
```

foreach point from points that fall in i range add constraint

```
model.AddConstraints("c{0}".F(pointIdx), a * point.x + b >= point.y);
```

Then add goal:

```
model.AddGoal("area", GoalKind.Minimize, goal);
```

And get the solution:

```
var solution = context.Solve(new SimplexDirective());
```

The solution works gives me a right answer but it takes a lot of time for simple case it takes 130 ms. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong? Where can I optimize ? 
Is Simplex method right for this case? 
Do we have better software solution then SolverFoundation for optimization.

Comment: I would not be too surprised if most of the time is spent on setting up the problem. Have you benchmarked the problem for a larger number of variables?

Comment: You could try to use indexed Decisions rather than scalar Decisions. An explanation is here: http://nathanbrixius.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/getting-solution-values-using-solver-foundation-services/

Comment: @AndersGustafsson the time that I have given you is from. solution.GetReport()

Answer (score 1):

try loading your model from OML string, enforce simplex solver to check if your problem is LP